# rg.NumberFormat = "0" showing object variable or with block variable not set error VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub LeadingZeros()
Dim cel As Range
Dim rg As Range
Dim mx As Integer: mx = 0
Dim cl As Variant
For Each cl In Selection
    If Len(cl) > mx Then mx = Len(cl)
Next

rg.NumberFormat = "0"   'this is showing error

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To mx - 2
    If mx = 1 Then Exit Sub
    rg.NumberFormat = rg.NumberFormat & "0"
Next
End Sub
```

Excel Column :
[image]

This is a code for filling up the values in cells with leading zeros. It worked just once, but after that not working. I didn't change the code.

Error : 
[image]

Comment: The error message says it all. No value is being set to `rg` therefore, error message...

Comment: So what do I have to do? Do I have to assign rg to selection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Yes,  you have to assign a value to `rg`. No programming language will magically know what your variables are meant to refer to. This MSDN article will help you out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the variable `rg` to a range. This is done with the word `Set`. In this example, the `rg` is assigned to `A1:A5` and it works further:

```
Sub LeadingZeros()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim mx As Integer: mx = 0
    Dim cl As Variant
    For Each cl In Selection
        If Len(cl) > mx Then mx = Len(cl)
    Next

    Set rg = Range("A1:A5")
    rg.NumberFormat = "0"   'this is showing error

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To mx - 2
        If mx = 1 Then Exit Sub
        rg.NumberFormat = rg.NumberFormat & "0"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did it on my own. Matched it with your answer, it was right. :)

Comment: @AmanDevrath - welcome. :) In general, whenever you are working with ranges,it is a good practice to mention the worksheet as well. Thus, `Set rg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5")`, otherwise it uses the `ActiveSheet` and this is not always what you want.